# Azure Virtual Machine low disk space

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have SQL Server running on a Large Azure Virtual Machine.

I have an attached disk where all the database MDFs, logging, backup and restore files are kept.  Nothing is kept on the C:.

I just logged in now and noticed that there is only 58MB left on the C:!  Is it possible to increase this disk space.  Is there something I can delete from the C:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot increase your os disk size. Not sure when you created your Virtual Machine. I know that a long time ago the size was set at (I believe) 30GB, and now the os disks should be around 127GB. You may want to check what size the OS disk is.

I'm not sure what chewed up your OS disk space except maybe some type of temporary os storage.